# Jquery Click Event fires on second click but not first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a script that gets some product data from a javascript object and adds it to a basket assigned to a `.click` function.

If I first click on the button to add a product, nothing happens. If I then click on another product's buy button, it adds the first product to the basket, and then it works from there, but is missing one product.

If I run the script on `pageload` instead of a `.click` - then it show all the products correctly.

Why does the script not fire on the first `.click`?

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hszxbmrx/13/

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".actionbutton").on("click", function(e) {
        $.each(retailerData.order.items,function(i,v){//get the item 
            var div = $('<div class="cartcont">')
            div.append('</br>'+'<img class="cartcont" src="' + v.imageURI +'" /><span class="art">' + v.label + '</span></br><span class="part">' + v.artno + '</span><span class="basketqty">' + v.qty + '</span><span class="price">'+ v.price + '</span>')
            $('div#headercart ul.acdropdown .carttable').append(div)
        })

        var nameDiv = document.createElement("td");
        nameDiv.id = 'totalIncExa';
        var text3 = document.createTextNode(retailerData.order.orderSum);
        nameDiv.appendChild(text3)
        document.body.appendChild(nameDiv);
        $("td#totalIncExa").appendTo("tr.ordersum");

        var nameDiv = document.createElement("td");
        nameDiv.id = 'vatTotala';
        var text3 = document.createTextNode(retailerData.order.orderVat);
        nameDiv.appendChild(text3)
        document.body.appendChild(nameDiv);
        $("td#vatTotala").appendTo("tr.ordervat");

        var nameDiv = document.createElement("td");
        nameDiv.id = 'orderTotala';
        var text3 = document.createTextNode(retailerData.order.orderSum);
        nameDiv.appendChild(text3)
        document.body.appendChild(nameDiv);
        $("td#orderTotala").appendTo("tr.ordersumtotal");
    });
});
```

Javascript Object:

```
var retailerData = {
"del": {
    "zip": "",
    "city": ""
},
"user": {
    "country": "",
    "phone": "",
    "nbrOrders": 0,
    "isPunchOut": false,
    "name": "",
    "salesPerson": "",
    "customerNo": "",
    "email": ""
},
"order": {
    "shippingSum": 0.0,
    "shippingFormatSum": "\u20AC0",
    "orderno": "0",
    "orderFormatSum": "\u20AC130",
    "voucher": "",
    "orderFormatVat": "\u20AC27,30",
    "currencySymbol": "\u20AC",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "orderVat": 27.3,
    "orderSum": 130.0,
    "items": [{
        "imageURI": "\/imgr\/8c82380c-65f5-43aa-83ad-fae1215b5b39\/70\/70",
        "qtyAvail": 7,
        "price": 130.0,
        "qty": 1,
        "artno": "D630-T7100-GE-REF",
        "vat": 27.3,
        "formatVat": "\u20AC27,30",
        "id": "52307",
        "label": "D630 C2D-T7100&#x2F;2GB&#x2F;80GB&#x2F;DVD&#x2F;14&#34;&#x2F;NO COA WLAN",
        "category": "Computers - Notebooks",
        "formatPrice": "\u20AC130",
        "manufacturer": "Dell"
    }]
  }
 }
```

Button:

```
<input type="button" id="pl52307buy" class="actionbutton" value="Köp" onclick="buy(this, 52307, null, 'pl52307qty',null, '/ajax/buy')">
```

Comment: can you create a `stack snippet` or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @SandeepNayak thats a bit hard, since the button have an ajaxfunction to call the product data into the variable, but I added a fiddle where the data is already populated.. But that will of course work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a button which calls (a) buy() on click. But you also binding a click event handler (b) on .actionbutton. The issue is that these events fire asynchronously. Since (a) is an ajax call it should take longer than (b) and therefore (b) doesn't have the data in "retailerData".

Instead of binding 2 click event handlers you can use the one handler for both. For example, buy() could load data and then its callback function would be responsible for rendering the cart.

Comment: hmm that sounds correct. How do i fix this? I don't have access to the ajax call - i can just just use Jquery or Vanilla Js to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Could fire the second event on a 'success' callback of the ajax event.

Comment: I am not sure what buy() is using for ajax requests but jQuery will fire an ajax event on completion. If jQuery is being used then you should be able to intercept it with .ajaxComplete. See http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/